# Need Example code on Spring Integration example for aws S3 as inBound and apache kafka as outbound

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

Need example on Spring Integration for aws s3 as inbound and apache kafka as outbound.

I want to read data from aws s3 and need to parse them and produce it to apache kafka topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code snippet. It isn't working but at least something to start from. Nobody here is going to write code for you:

```
<bean id="s3SessionFactory" 
           class="org.springframework.integration.aws.support.S3SessionFactory"/>

<int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter channel="s3Channel"
                   session-factory="s3SessionFactory"
                   filename-pattern="*.txt"
                   local-directory="."
                   remote-directory-expression="'my_bucket'">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter>


<int:transformer input-channel="s3Channel" output-channel="kafkaChannel"
       ref="myTransformer"/>

<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter
                                kafka-template="template"
                                channel="kafkaChannel"
                                topic="foo"
                                message-key-expression="'bar'"
                                partition-id-expression="2">
</int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                    <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="localhost:9092" />
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank You! @Artem Bilan. I will try to implement with your reference code